# Remove private data from URL

Tags: privacy, url

I would like to have a tool that automatically removes private data from URLs, for example session IDs and any parameter that is not absolut necessary for the URL to work.

The tool should be compatible to as many sites as possible, but at least with these:

- Amazon
- Google
- Google Mail
- Google Drive
- Microsoft OneDrive
- Dropbox

The tool of choice should fit as many of these additional requirements as possible:

- available as Add-In for Firefox
- available as Extension for Chrome
- usable from iOS in any way
- open source, if possible

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to write rules for each site, I can recommend [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/redirector/).

It meets all your requirements: It's available for Firefox and Chrome, works in iOS, and is open-source.

With Redirector, you can rewrite any URL to any other URL.  If you're good with Regular Expressions, it's exceptionally powerful.  Even without Regular Expressions, it supports easy-to-use wildcards that will handle most cases.